# SQL Where Clause with CASE & NOT IN Condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a select query with where Clause. Now I have to add additional condition in where clause based on user access. If user does not have access then need to include additional condition in where clause, else if user have access then there is no additional logic.

For example:

```
Select * from TableA where ID > 100
```

Additional Logic:
If user does not have access to Admin Page then @X= 0 and if does not have access to External Page then @Y = 0.

I need to include the below logic in where clause:

```
if (@X = 0 and @y=0) then 
pagecode not in ('admin','external') 
else if(@x=0 and @y=1) then
pagecode not in ('admin')
else if(@x=1 and @y=0) then
pagecode not in ('external')
else
no additional logic in where clause
```

How to implement this using case in where clause.

Comment: Why do you need to do this using `case`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE in WHERE as Shown below:

```
    WHERE 1=(
             CASE WHEN @X = 0 and @y = 0 and pagecode not in ('admin','external') THEN 1
                  WHEN @x = 0 and @y = 1 and pagecode not in ('admin') THEN 1
                  WHEN @x = 1 and @y = 0 and pagecode not in ('external') THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END
            )
```

this will not return any row if @x=1 and @y=1.
If you want to return all rows if @x=1 and @y=1

```
    WHERE 1=(
             CASE WHEN @X = 0 and @y = 0 and pagecode not in ('admin','external') THEN 1
                  WHEN @x = 0 and @y = 1 and pagecode not in ('admin') THEN 1
                  WHEN @x = 1 and @y = 0 and pagecode not in ('external') THEN 1
                  WHEN @x = 1 and @y = 1 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sparse on details here. The ELSE is pretty vague but I was assuming that both variables would equal 1. But we don't even know the datatype of those so not totally sure. My guess is something like this.

```
where 
(
    @X = 0 
    and 
    @y = 0
    and pagecode not in ('admin','external') 
)
OR
(
    @x = 0 
    and 
    @y = 1
    and
    pagecode not in ('admin')
)
OR
(
    @x = 1 
    and 
    @y = 0
    and
    pagecode not in ('external')
)
OR
(
    @x = 1 
    and 
    @y = 1
)
```

Be warned. This approach can have some serious performance problems. Gail Shaw has written about this [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and a follow up [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/). You can also read Erland Sommarskog's article [here](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: "This can be a serious performance problem. See the article from Gail Shaw in my comments above. But this is definitely a very common way of handling this type of thing."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - touche. I will add those links to my answer. Definitely proof of how common it is. :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
WHERE ID > 100 
      AND ((pagecode != 'admin' and X = 0) or X= 1)
      AND ((pagecode != 'external' and Y = 0) or Y= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks

> How to implement this using case in where clause.

I thought I'd do a little experimentation.   After discovering some interesting limitations, I found a way.

You should be able to adapt this successful experiment:

```
SELECT 'boom'
WHERE 'a' NOT IN (
    SELECT CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN 'a' ELSE '' END
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'b' ELSE '' END
)
```

Note the `ELSE ''` is important.   Without an `ELSE` the `CASE` will supply a `NULL` for that row, and that will mess up your `IN()` condition.

By the way, this isn't how I would look to solve your actual problem, but it does answer the question, so if you really need to use a `CASE` expression for some reason, this is how it can be done.